# iOS AVPlayerViewController distinguish user actions to exit Picture-in-Picture mode

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit, picture-in-picture

In my iOS Video Player, when in the Picture-in-Picture mode (PIP), how can I handle specific user actions like `close` or `restore`. The existing delegate provides a way to know when PIP mode is stopped but I wan't different behavior to be executed on different user actions:

- close - let the controller go and keep it closed
- restore - re-present the player and continue playback

[image]

After implementing `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate`, AVPlayerViewController calls the following functions regardless of what button user tapped:

```
playerViewControllerWillStopPictureInPicture
playerViewControllerDidStopPictureInPicture
```

I also defined method `restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler` but it seems not getting called for some reason on exit from the PIP mode.

```
    func restoreUserInterfaceForFullScreenExit(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    
    func restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStop(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(true)
    }
```

Comment: How do you change playback buttons values to 10 seconds? My backward and forward buttons have 15 seconds value by default, but I can't find the way to change them.

Comment: I believe it is automatically picked based on video length. I didn't customize this behavior at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I have view that contained AVPLayer `playerView` and it has delegate:

```
var pipControllerDelegate: AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate?
playerView.pipControllerDelegate = self
```

I've implemented required methods by the following way and it works for me:

```
extension PlayerView: AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate {
func pictureInPictureControllerDidStopPictureInPicture(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController) {
    close()
}

func pictureInPictureController(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController,
                                  restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let isPipPlaying = (pictureInPictureController.playerLayer.player?.timeControlStatus == .playing)
        if isPipPlaying {
            play()
        } else {
            paused()
        }
        completionHandler(true)
}
```

May be your delegate bacomes nil at some place of code?

Comment: oh, this is great, I have implemented the wrong delegate... I mean I didn't implement the PIP delegate. Thanks for the sample. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

To restore your player and continue playing you should use                                `playerViewController(_:restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler:)` method of `AVPictureInPictureControllerDelegate`.

This method is called before `playerViewControllerWillStopPictureInPicture(_:)` and `playerViewControllerDidStopPictureInPicture(_:)` as it is described in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_in_a_standard_player).

Comment: I have implanted these two methods but they are not getting called at all for some reason. I have modified my question to specify code how I implemented it